# Cannot set the accessibility of navigation tabs through AD groups

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, active-directory, groups, audience-targeting

We have a Portal developed by SharePoint 2016 Enterprise.

In this, there are Navigation tabs.

Different groups can access different tabs.

Then I set particular group for that tab in "Target Audience" of navigation.

If I add the user directly into the SharePoint group, the users are able to access those tabs.

When I add the AD ( Active Directory ) group into the SharePoint group, the users are not able to access those tabs.

Is there additional configuration needed for AD groups such that the tabs are accessible to respective groups?

Comment: The AD Group in question is an AD security group, not a distribution group, right?
And it does not consist of other AD groups?

Comment: What are you using to generate or control your tabs? Are the groups nested? Have you compiled the audiences? If so does the membership of the audience reflect the correct group membership?

Comment: AD Group is an AD security group.
There are different AD groups used for this purpose but they're not nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granted Replicating Directory Changes Permission to the account used for synchronisation of user profile service.

Then I added the AD group into the target audience of "Navigation settings".

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you UPS have configured and correctly .
2. Do a full user profile synchronization .
3. Make sure the service account for the User Profile Synchronization Service did not have "Replicating Directory Changes" permissions in Active Directory .

Comment: The service account needs Replicating Directory Changes.